# How can I get Apache to serve index files from subdirectories that have the same name as the subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was just asked to work on a terrible site that the client is running off IIS. I can't make changes to the live server so I attempted to install the site on my testing server running Apache.

The site's homepage is up and running but I cannot navigate to any subdirectories. The nav menu has links like /about-us/ -- however, there is no index.php file in the about-us directory. Instead there is a file named about-us.php.

If I was getting paid to fix the site up I would do the work to rename the files and/or links, but for now I just want to get this thing running so I can make my CSS and content edits and be done with it. I assume there is some easier way (using htaccess?) to dynamically tell Apache that, when directed to a subdirectory, look for /foo/foo.php instead of /foo/index.php -- right now all I get is a directory listing or permission denied if I turn indexing off.

I've been Googling around but can't find anything that looks like the same problem -- can one of you rewrite gurus please point me in the right direction?

Comment: They probably had `rewrites` that simply removed the .php file extension. That's easy to do and bit more common in Apache. Do a web Search for `remove php extension .htaccess`. You don't need to rename any files.

Comment: @PanamaJack that doesn't work, that just removes the php extension...that would work if my sub page php files were in the root, but the way this site is laid out it is still trying to browse to the subdirectories instead of serving the php file in each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for you is to set the appropiate DirectoryIndex for each directory as in:

```
<Directory /path/to/about-us>
    DirectoryIndex about-us.php
</Directory>
```

You can also define a single "controller" in case there is no index page found, this is done like:

```
FallBackResource /index.php
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more automated/dynamic, but this does work!